# tfjs-node-gpu not using GPU

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflowjs

I am trying to use run ML code on GPU developed using the node package **tfjs-node-gpu** . When I try doing so the program is running but I am unable to see any process being added to the GPU. I suspect that my program is not using GPU for this reason. I have just installed the package and used in the code referring it. Is this the right way do I need to do anything more to make my TF node.js code run on GPU.

I am seeing tthe below error before my code starts executing

[image]

And the below is the GPU logs when my program is running

[image]

TIA

Comment: Giving us your code could help

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and installing node-gpu again?

Comment: Yes I have tried doing that , but did not help.

Comment: And no errors or warings during installation? Using the current version?

Comment: No errors while installing but got the above posted error while executing.Do I need to do anything in the code other than importing node-gpu?

Comment: Not that I know of, just `const tfjs = require('node-gpu')`

Comment: These are my actual import statements 
`const tf = require("@tensorflow/tfjs-node");`
`const dicomParser = require('dicom-parser');`

Comment: That's just the node version not the cpu nor the gpu one, you need `'@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu'`

Comment: sorry I was using the same '@tensorflow/tfjs-node-gpu' . Missed it in the comment

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel any idea about the issue?

Comment: I have solved this myself , that was totally problem with NVIDIA drivers , uninstalling and installing them solved my issue.